# C# Transparent Panels?

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

so I'm challenging myself by making a game-engine using GDI.

So far I've managed to make made a few games using GDI - however I have recent hit a problem I'd like some help with.

I have implemented a UI system and have found out that the GDI `Translate` function moves the *entire* canvas. Subsequently all my mouse coordinates are offset causing my UI system to not work as expected.

Question: Is there any way to make a Panel transparent on the Paint method?

I have tried to set the clear colour to transparent but that only makes the panel black.

Comment: Just a thought. I haven’t tested before but, have you tried setting the backcolor in your code using. Colors.FromArgb(50,0,0,0) to set the transparency?

Comment: Yeah sadly it did not work

Comment: What UI framework are you working with? Winforms? wpf? web?

Comment: I am using winforms c#

Answer (score 0):

I cannot point to a source for this, but I did some testing now and my explanation is as following:

When I set the BackgroundColor of the panel to Colors.FromArgb(50,0,0,0) then this worked, because whenever I changed the Backgroundcolor of the Form the panel lives on, then the color of the form shined through the panel.

But: the other controls that lived behind this panel have not been visible all the time. I am sure that for performance reasons the rendering of the controls only happens if they are visible to the user, that means they are not coverd by an other control. So the color of the form is shining through because the transparent color actually works, but the controls behind the panel are not rendered because they are covered by an other control.

You have to write your own control:

```
  public class TransparentPanel : Panel
  {
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
      get
      {
        var cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
        return cp;
      }
    }
  }
```

this tells windows, that the control is transparent and the controls that are are in z-order behind this control have to be rendered, too.